# When using click-once deployment, is there a 'Publish Date' property available

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

I want to show the publish date in the About dialog.

Comment: I think you need to provide more specific information if you want anyone to answer this question.

Comment: The question is specific enough. ClickOnce is a .Net-specific deployment technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. ApplicationDeployment class exposes only the [CurrentVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentversion(VS.80).aspx) property, not the publish time.

You could use the revision field to store the date of the build to show in the About dialog.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no direct way in Click-Once to do that.

Here is a **workaround**: You'd have to load the file in question (DLL or EXE) into a FileInfo object and get the modification date off it.

```
FileInfo oMyFile = new
   FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

DateTime oBuildDate = oMyFile.LastWriteTime // or LastWriteTimeUtc - don't use "CreationTime"
```

*Note: Technically, it's not the publishing date, but the date of the assembly on the disk of the client. You have to check if Click-Once doesn't change that date*